# Merge results from two has_many associations with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users. Users can poke other users, as well as poke themselves. Each poke is directional, and group pokes don't exist. I want to list all pokes (incoming or outgoing) for a given user, without duplicating self-pokes (which exist as both incoming_ and outgoing_pokes).

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :outgoing_pokes, :class_name => "Poke", :foreign_key => :poker_id
  has_many :incoming_pokes, :class_name => "Poke", :foreign_key => :pokee_id
end

class Poke < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poker, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :pokee, :class_name => "User"
end
```

I tried creating a method in the `User` model to merge the pokes:

```
def all_pokes
  outgoing_pokes.merge(incoming_pokes)
end
```

but that returns only the self-pokes (those that are both incoming_ and outgoing_pokes). Ideas? Is there a clean way to do this using associations directly?

Also, in the merged list, it'd be great to have two booleans for each poke to record how they're related to the current user. Something like `outgoing` and `incoming`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason your `all_pokes` method is returning only self-pokes is because `outgoing_pokes` is not an array yet, but an AR relationship that you can chain on. `merge`, in this case, combines the queries before executing them.

What you want is to actually perform the queries and merge the result sets:

```
def all_pokes
  (outgoing_pokes.all + incoming_pokes.all).uniq
end
```

...or you could write your own query:

```
def all_pokes
  Poke.where('poker_id = ? OR pokee_id = ?', id, id)
end
```

#### Determining whether it's incoming or outgoing:

```
# in poke.rb
def relation_to_user(user)
  if poker_id == user.id
    poker_id == pokee_id ? :self : :poker
  elsif pokee_id == user.id
    :pokee
  else
    :none
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice. Both work, though the ordering is a little nicer on the latter. Is there any rails magic that will generate a query like that for me? It appears that `merge` is doing that, but using an `AND` between the two conditions. Maybe there's one that will use an `OR`? Also, any ideas on adding those booleans?

Comment: I don't think there's a way of triggering an `or` like this in AR, but I would love to be shown otherwise. To find out whether this is incoming or outgoing you could add a method to poke. I'll update to demonstrate.

Comment: Ah, too bad. `relation_to_user` could work, though since we have self-pokes, we'd need another option `:both`.. something like: `poker_id == user.id ? (pokee_id == user.id ? :both : :poker) : :pokee`

Comment: Nested ternary operators are kinda ugly; I updated to account for more cases. It isn't super elegant or anything, but at least the intent of the code should be clear.

Comment: ...especially with all those extra `:`s... 

Answer (score 13):

Now that Rails 5 has `OR` queries, there is a very readable solution.

```
def pokes
  outgoing_pokes.or(incoming_pokes)
end
```

I left off the `all` in the method name since it is now returning an ActiveRelation and other methods can be chained.

```
@user.pokes.where(...).includes(...)
```