# has_many through multiple sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a `has_many through` relation with multiple sources.

For example a game has a `home_team` and `away_team` and a tournament has multiple games.

What is the best way to get all teams in the tournament using a has_many through games relation.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
class Tournament
  has_many :teams, :through => :games, :source => :home_team, :uniq => true
end
```

but I want some way to make it act like:

```
class Tournament
  has_many :teams, :through => :games, :source => [:home_team, :away_team], :uniq => true
end
```

EDIT: The many to many relationship is not my problem. Is there a good way to get all the teams in the tournament assuming the structure as follows.

```
class Game
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tournaments
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => Team, :foreign_key => :home_team_id
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => Team, :foreign_key => :away_team_id
end

class Tournament
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
end
```

Is there a way to do `Tournament.teams`?

Comment: Had a similar issue and ended up changing my schema to work around it, but one option I looked at was a method using `.merge` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486027/merge-results-from-two-has-many-associations-with-the-same-model

Edit: Thinking about it more, I bet the rails way to do it is single table inheritance where home and away games have a parent abstract class `Game` that provides the join table. I'll try that next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending some time trying to find a built in solution I just ended up writing a custom query called teams in games. It joins teams to games twice through team_1 and team_2 and checks to see if any of the list of game id's are in either of these two joins.

This solution isn't great since it requires multiple queries (One of which is just a huge list of all game ids), but I spent a lot of time trying to come up with another way and couldn't. At least this way works.

I'd love to learn a better way.

Code inside of games:

```
def self.teams
  joined_tables = Team.joins(:home_team).joins(:away_team)
  joined_tables.where('games.id in (?) or  away_team_games.id in  (?)',
                   select(:id), select(:id)).uniq
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Define models like this:

```
class Tournament
  has_many :games
  has_many :teams, :through => :games
end

class Game
  belongs_to :torunament
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team
  has_many :games
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :games
end
```

And then call in controller, or wherever:

```
tournament.teams
```

EDIT:

you could define `scope` for this kind of problem in you `Tournament` model. This is more like some custom query, rather it is supported by rails out of the box. Or at least I can't remember at this very moment.

you can look how to use them.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope
http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/02/19/scopes-in-rails-3/

You can build up a query that would get all the teams. You can create any query you like.

Comment: A game only has a single team in this example or am I missing something?

Comment: ouh, yes, you are absolutely right. In speed I have overlooked that. thanks for pointing out to me.

Comment: I like when someone puts `-1` and put no reason for it. Where accepted solution has an ugly custom query. Horay.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but to be fair your answer didn't come close to answering my question as my previous comment pointed out. I don't think there was any way to do  it without the ugly query. Not sure if that's still the case since I haven't used rails in a while.

Comment: Yes, okay, I got it. In a sense I haven't used your model names like `away_team` and `home_team`, I can see that now, but in Rails, if you are writing the query like the one below, then you definetly know you are on the wrong path, as in Rails mostly everything can be done in a clean and nice way.

Comment: :) Yeah thats why I asked the question. I don't think there is a clean way to do that particular query. I would love to be proved wrong though

Comment: Omg, you are the *Asker* :D I have just realized that! :)) hehe. Hm, then I totally deserved the -1 :) Hm, regarding the answer, a bit cleaner would be `Team.find(tournament.games.home_team_id + tournament.games.away_team_ids)` but it is not that optimized though

Comment: @Aleks thank you. What if we added another model in there. Suppose each team has many :players, and each player has many :fingers. Would you know how i could get from the tournament to the players and vice versa - i.e. what would i have to write in the model?