# has_many, :through => :multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like a relationship along the lines of

```
has_many :foos, :through => :multiple
```

models

Site:

```
has_many :pages
has_many :files
```

Page:

```
belongs_to :site
has_many :legacy_url_redirects, as: :redirect_resourceable
```

File:

```
belongs_to :site
has_many :legacy_url_redirects, as: :redirect_resourceable
```

LegacyUrlRedirects

```
belongs_to :redirect_resourceable, :polymorphic => true
```

What I would like to do is in the `Site` model add something like:

```
has_many :legacy_url_redirects, :through => [:pages, :files]
```

Or an equally good alternative.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is what i did:
Site model:

```
def legacy_url_redirects(options = {})
  file_where = {"files.site_id" => self.id}.merge(options)
  page_where = {"pages.site_id" => self.id}.merge(options)

  LegacyUrlRedirect.includes(:file).where(file_where) + LegacyUrlRedirect.includes(:page).where(page_where) 
end
```

I also added the `:pages` and `:files` relationships to the `LegacyUrlRedirects` model with help from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16124295/1141264

**SECOND EDIT:**

I refactored the fix a little so that its a manually written `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between the three tables. Also not specifying the select part of the query when doing a join implies `@readonly = true` on the records returned.

Comment: it looks like your files and pages should be subclasses of a more general model. After which you can put the :through => ... pointing to the superclass of both the page and file.

Comment: Maybe this other answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15489963/1022165

Comment: @Enermis Good idea, but apart from this relationship and a url its the only thing they will share, not sure it warrants a superclass.

Comment: @Thayago B. Rodrigues I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Thayago B. Rodrigues eager loading the relationship brings up an ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError

Comment: oh no, why would you do that? just create two `has_many` relations.

Comment: Can you update table structure